# Picking up Changed Checkbox from Programmatic Check/Uncheck

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, coffeescript

Given:

## HTML

```
<input id='a' value='bbb' type='checkbox'>
<button id='btn'>
click to change checkbox
</button>
```

## Coffeescript

```
$('#a').change ->
    console.log 'asdfasdf'

$('#btn').click ->
    document.getElementById('a').checked=true
    document.getElementById('a').checked=false
    document.getElementById('a').checked=true
```

I expected to see 3 console output log messages when I first pressed the button. But I saw none.

How can I modify my `on change` function to log a message when the `checked` status changes of my checkbox?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because changing value or property programmatically doesn't trigger user events and if you need event to trigger you need to do that yourself

```
$('#btn').click ->
    var $a = $('#a')
    for(var i=0; i<3; i++){
         setTimeout(function(){
            $a.prop('checked', !$a[0].checked).change();
         },i*500)
   }
```

Answer (score 0):

I hope this is wat your'e  asking

**Button click function**

```
$('#btn').click(function(){
 var isChecked  = $('#a').is(":checked");
 if (isChecked) {
                console.log("CheckBox checked.");
            } else {
                console.log("CheckBox not checked.");
            }

});
```

**Checkbox change function**

```
$('#a').change(function(){
 var isChecked  = $(this).is(":checked");
 if (isChecked) {
                console.log("CheckBox checked.");
            } else {
                console.log("CheckBox not checked.");
            }

});
```

Answer (score 0):

You could do it one of two ways.

You could trigger a click on the checkbox instead of setting it explicitly to true or false if all you want to do is toggle it.

```
$('#btn').click ->
    $('#a').click()
```

Or you could trigger a change after setting the checked property.

```
$('#btn').click ->
    $('#a').prop('checked', true).change()
```

Setting the checked value in javascript doesn't trigger the change handler automatically (the same way using .val() to set a value on an input doesn't trigger the change handler)